# Installing Docker on Redhat AWS EC2 Instance(RHEL_7.9)

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, redhat

I have created an Redhat EC2 Instance in AWS.
I am trying to install Jenkins as a Docker Image inside that Redhat EC2 Instance.
I am following the below URl to install Docker on AWS

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/

But I am facing issue after adding that repositoy, I guess Yum is not able to get the repository

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7Server/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.



 One of the configured repositories failed (Docker CE Stable - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=docker-ce-stable ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable docker-ce-stable
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=docker-ce-stable

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=docker-ce-stable.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-ce-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7Server/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

I tried running the following command after that error(just hit and trail)

```
yum-config-manager --save --setopt=docker-ce-stable.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

But its not able to find

```
No package docker-ce available.
No package docker-ce-cli available.
No package containerd.io available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Can someone help me with some documentation or any blog to install docker on Redhat platform

I am Using **RHEL_7.9** version

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you connect to download the repo from the EC2 command line?